# pyspark: isIN and isNOT IN replcaement with another df column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

i'm trying to filter dataframe in pyspark using "isin"
also tried another way of filtering.

unable to get the correct result.
getting error of Spark Array literal.
can anyone help

```
One way:

df1.select("COL1").distinct().show()
df2.select(('col1').isin(df1.select("COL1").distinct()))

-------
Second way :

uniquelist=df1.select("COL1").distinct().collect()
df2.filter(F.col('col1').contains(uniqueVIN)).show()
```

can anyone help me solve the error :

An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.

I also have to perform a "is not in"

```
data_array =  np.array(df_list.select("f_col").collect())
df_filtered = df_2.filter(~df_2["colname"].isin([data_array]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`collect()` returns a list of `Row` objects, you need to get the values from the rows before passing it to `isin` column method:

```
unique_list = [r["COL1"] for r in df1.select("COL1").distinct().collect()]

df2.filter(F.col('col1').isin(unique_list)).show()
```

However, you should use join for this:

- Use `left_semi` to get row from `df2` with corresponding rows from `df1`:

  ```
  df2.join(df1, df1["COL1"] == df2["col1"], "left_semi").show()
  ```
- And `left_anti` to get rows from `df2` that have no corresponding values in `df1`:

  ```
  df2.join(df1, df1["COL1"] == df2["col1"], "left_anti").show()
  ```